# Robot won't connect to a new connection on our SQL server to AWS

Tags: sql, automation, robotics, rpa, g1ant

I’ve been connecting the G1ANT robot to SQL server and it works fine.
However now I've created a new connection on our SQL server to AWS but it's not connecting to it.

This connection string works fine:

`Server=GARDSQLDEV01;Database=ColumbusMk1;Trusted_Connection=True;`

This connection string does not work:

`Server=columbus-dev.csalh0f00gat.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com,1433;Database=ColumbusMk1; User ID=sa; Password=***;   Trusted_Connection=True;`

Replaced the password with *** for security reasons.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use special character ‴long text‴ for long connection strings with spaces. It should work fine:

```
database ‴Server=columbus-dev.csalh0f00gat.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com,
1433;Database=ColumbusMk1; User ID=sa; Password=********;   Trusted_Connection=True;‴
```

Good luck!